# Rotating figures to point to the outside edge

Tags: graphics, floats, double-sided, rotating

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX `book` style. I have a large figure that I want to rotate to make it viewable sideways. I can do this with the `includegraphics` option `angle=90`.

My question: Is there a way to automatically rotate through -90 degrees on even pages and 90 degrees on odd pages so that the lower edge of the figure is always at the outside edge of the book page?

Comment: Generally speaking, many people think this is not the best way to do rotation; I believe the reader will usually expect to rotate the book 90° clockwise, so it may be best to stick with rotating the figures by +90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating)  package and its `sidewaysfigure` environment. (The following example must be compiled two times for correct rotation on even/odd pages.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
{\Huge (Picture)}
\caption{A figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
{\Huge (Picture)}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```